# When does $n-2$ divide $n-5$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We got asked this question today in a national exam:

$n$ is a positive integer; find the values of $n$ for which $n-2$ divides $n-5$.

Comment: Surely you have a typo.  $n-2$ is larger than $n-5$ and so never divides $n-5$.  If a natural number $a$ is a divisor of a natural number $x$ you have that there is some natural number $b$ such that $ab=x$ and you would have $a\leq ab = x$ implying that there cannot be any divisors strictly greater than the number they divide.  Maybe you mean for $n-2$ *to be divisible by* $n-5$, a different statement than $n-2$ dividing $n-5$.

Comment: @JMoravitz what if $n=1 \text{ or } 3$ because the numbers themselves could be negative.

Comment: $\!\bmod n\!-\!2\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv 2}\ $ so $\ 0\equiv \color{#c00}n\!-\!5\equiv \color{#c00}2-5\equiv -3,\ $ so $\,n\!-\!2\mid 3.\ $ I used $\bmod\,$ since you tagged it "modular-arithmetic"

Comment: @Jmoravitz i had the same idea as yours that there s a typo but no!

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{n-5}{n-2}=1-\frac{3}{n-2}.$$
So we want the quantity $\frac{3}{n-2}$ to be an integer. Now ask yourself for what values of $n \in \{1,2,3,4, \ldots \}$ will $n-2$ divide $3$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$n-5=n-2-3$$ so we get $$\frac{n-5}{n-2}=1-\frac{3}{n-2}$$